# Inhereiting only some of the parent constructors arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Let's say I have a parent object:

```
function Shape(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  this.x = x;
  ...
```

I want the child object to inherit `x`, `y` and `exists` how do acheive this?
I had an idea to call Shape constructor and overwrite `velX` and `velY` afterwards like this:

```
function EvilCircle(x, y, exists) {
  Shape.call(this, x, y, velX, velY, exists);
  this.velX = 10;
  ...
```

This doesn't seem lika an elegant solution, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the correct value directly?

```
function EvilCircle(x, y, exists) {
  Shape.call(this, x, y, 10, ?, exists);
  ...
```

(You kind of have to anyway, because `velX` should not be defined there.)